# Facebook messenger webhook not verifying

Tags: facebook, get, httprequest, facebook-messenger-bot

I am testing facebook messenger webhook,
to register that i have set necessary parameters
here is my php code for that,

## Code:

```
$postData = request()->all();

        // Your verify token. Should be a random string.
        $verfityTocken = "fR8Eu5Wj9m9WTLvA0vIZYMenoTvu51bdGaL70FFb9pHhSeySbLHa0Q5cTLaJ";

        // Parse the query params
        $mode = $postData['hub_mode'];
        $token = $postData['hub_verify_token'];
        $challenge = $postData['hub_challenge'];

        // Checks if a token and mode is in the query string of the request
        if ($mode && $token) {

            // Checks the mode and token sent is correct
            if ($mode === 'subscribe' && $token === $verfityTocken) {

                // Responds with the challenge token from the request
                //echo 'WEBHOOK_VERIFIED';

                return response(request()->input("hub_challenge"), 200);

            } else {
                // Responds with '403 Forbidden' if verify tokens do not match
                return response('403 Forbidden', 403);
            }
        }
```

Now on verifying webhook from messanger panel i getting error as show in the image

[image]

#### I can't understand why there is trailing data `\u0033Clink` in received.

Comment: `\u0033` is an encoded `<`, so this looks like your system just outputs HTML code in addition to the challenge – `<link …>` But you have given us no information whatsoever what library/framework you are using there, so hard to tell what actually causes it. It is not even clear what context the above code is in - seeing as `return` is used, it is probably a function/method inside of a broader routing system(?) … anyway, check the docs for whatever you are using there, for what you have to do to prevent it from giving the “normal output” afterwards as well.

Comment: I am calling this request in php laravel 5.6 framework

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your help i have add headers in response and it's working now

Comment: @Priyank can you please answer how you make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone still trying to solve this, you need to return the `hub_challenge` number in plain text.

I did it in ruby like this:

```
def accept_request

    render plain: params['hub.challenge']
end
```

Comment: still not working for me. I'm returning the hub challenge code with 200 status code :(